# AWS adds metadata to file content when using uploadUrl

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, postman, aws-java-sdk

I'm using the next code to get upload instructuion with uploadUrl:

```
public UploadInstruction getUploadUrl() {
    final var objectKey = getObjectKey(generateUniqueFileKey());
    final var url = amazonS3.generatePresignedUrl(s3Properties.getBucket(), objectKey,
            calculateExpirationDate(s3Properties.getDownload().getUrlExpiration()), HttpMethod.PUT);
    return new UploadInstruction(url, getFileKey(objectKey));
}
```

I get the URL via my api and use Postman to send PUT request. But when I'm using this URL to upload a file I found that AWS adds some metadata at the beginning of my file, like "Content-type: Application octets stream....". Is it a bug? How to avoid adding extra info to uploaded files with was upload URL?

UPDATED:
For example, I want to upload simple txt file with the next text:

```
test
```

When I uploaded to S3 via uploadUrl, after downloading I get a file with the next content:

```
----------------------------174475527638909501568708
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""; filename="test.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

test
----------------------------174475527638909501568708--
```

Also, I changed the file name when generating uploadUrl. Also, when I uploaded zip archive I can't unpack it after downloading from s3 bucket. But all works when I uploading files via AWS CLI.

The address in PUT request is uploadUrl. My headers which postman added are next:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some information [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/547).
Usually when uploading files used form-data:

```
var fd = new FormData();
var file = document.getElementById('file')[0];
fd.append('file',file);
```

It is necessary to use next:

```
var upload = document.getElementById('file');
var file = upload.files[0];
```

Full code:

```
<form method="put" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myform">

        <div >
            <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
            <input type="button" class="button" value="Upload" id="but_upload">
        </div>
    </form>
```

Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#but_upload").click(function(){

        var upload = document.getElementById('file');
var file = upload.files[0];

        $.ajax({
            url: '<uploadURL>',
            type: 'put',
            data: file,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(response){
                if(response != 0){
                    alert('file uploaded');
                }else{
                    alert('file not uploaded');
                }
            },
        });
    });
});
```

In Postman it is necessary to use binary instead form-data to attach a file:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Amazon always adds certain meta data to your S3 objects. A full list of them can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#object-metadata). According to Amazon `There are two kinds of metadata: system metadata and user-defined metadata`. Certain meta data properties such as content type are automatically added.

> - Metadata such as object creation date is system controlled, where only Amazon S3 can modify the value.
> - Other system metadata, such as the storage class configured for the object and whether the object has server-side encryption enabled, are examples of system metadata whose values you control. If your bucket is configured as a website, sometimes you might want to redirect a page request to another page or an external URL. In this case, a webpage is an object in your bucket. Amazon S3 stores the page redirect value as system metadata whose value you control.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I understand it is a meta-information that I can read when opening an object in AWS CLI. But I think it should not be in the body of the file. I added more info to the question.

Comment: Hi, how are you seeing this? Looks like thats the headers of the request

Comment: I open it in notepad. Also, file size increased. It was 4 byte first